# Getting so libs strings and sort in GNU/Linux bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep, terminal, gnu

i am trying to get in order the strings from the system base libraries

First the commands i use for this :

«reset» is a command for clean the screen
«strings is a command for gather information from /lib64/libc.so.6
«grep» is a command for search and print coincidences
«sort» is for re-arrange the order of data
«sed» is for text editing without interaction
«uniq» is for remove duplicate entries

well using all together :

```
reset ; strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep "^[GLIBC]" -m23 | sort -r | grep -o -P '.{0,3}GLIBC_.{0,4}' | sed 's/\.$//' | uniq -u
```

Output :

```
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.23
GLIBC_2.22
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.16 
GLIBC_2.15 
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.13 
GLIBC_2.12 
GLIBC_2.11 
GLIBC_2.10
```

i want the order be :

```
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_2.13
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.15
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.22
GLIBC_2.23
```

or in reverse order :

```
GLIBC_2.23
GLIBC_2.22
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.15
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.13
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.4
```

I am under Slackware64 14.2, someone can tell me if posible re-organizate the output like i want ?

well i don't know why GLIBC_2.{19,20,21} are missing from the output xD

Comment: It sounds like you want something more like `grep -E "^GLIBC_.{3,4}$" | sort -V` or perhaps `grep -E "^GLIBC_2\.[0-9]{1,2}$" | sort -V` - note the absence of `[` and `]`, which make it match any of the characters G,L,I,B,C

Comment: Do you have sample output of `strings | grep 'GLIBC'` ? I.e. why not `| grep -o '^GLIBC_[0-9.]*' | sort -uV` - or perhaps `^GLIBC_[0-9][^ ]*` if any version has letters.

Comment: Thanks a lot the command : 
reset ; strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep -E "^GLIBC_.{3,4}$" | sort -V | uniq

is the exact i want.

Comment: `reset` isn't necessary for this problem.